# Fill DataGrid with a custom query

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I'm trying to fill my DataGrid with a custom query I have written which binds two tables. The query is stored in my dataset `(dbPBDataset.xsd)` under the table adapters `(TransactionTableAdapter)` and it's called `'qryActivePlayers,GetDataby1`'.

What I want to do is to `add a datagrid view on my form and load the result` of that query on it. 
I'm using the GUI tools of Visual Studio. For any other queries it works fine but I believe because this one binds two tables, it gives me errors such as: `Constrain Option Unhandled "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."`

This is the query

```
SELECT c.Name, c.CustomerID, t.TransactionID, t.Buyin, t.EndTime, t.Type, c.Surname FROM [Transaction] AS t INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID WHERE (t.EndTime = '1/1/1900')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: without seeing source its difficult to say but it is prob. exactly what it says. there is some constraint failing in one of the tables where say a value is expect but is null. It could be a field is dirty in that it has too many chars. It's going to be something like that though. I would look at the relationship and also all required fields and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query works fine in the query editor. Here it is: SELECT     c.Name, c.CustomerID, t.TransactionID, t.Buyin, t.EndTime, t.Type, c.Surname
FROM         [Transaction] AS t INNER JOIN
                      Customer AS c ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE     (t.EndTime = '1/1/1900')

Comment: The weird thing is that on the results preview I get some extra, empty columns

Comment: Maybe go into SQL management studio directly can wire up some raw queries and take a peek. bet a hundy u have some dirty data.